# Correct Way to configure Multiple Angular 2 Apps on a Single Domain with Firebase Hosting

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-database, firebase-hosting

**This is structure of My Project (not of angular App)**

```
.
├── App
|   ├── Login
|   ├── Projects
|   └── Settings
| 
├── Store (public but part of app)
|

.
├── Site
|   ├── Homepage
|   └── About
|
├── Help
|  

.   
└── Blog
```

1. Web app is designed with Angular 4 and Firebase Hosting/Database and
   don't need SEO, but other public pages will.
2. Public pages like about, homepage,help are designed with pure HTML, CSS and Vanilla JavaScript and Google Analytics for starter
3. Blog will be made wither with angular, react or vue

---

**This is what I expect or intend to build:**

- mysite.com --- points of Homepage
- /about to about page
- /help to help page
- /blog to Blog Which is project in its own
- /projects to user projects
- /tasks to user tasks
- /store, /settings to corresponding page or component

**How other major players do it:**

1. Google Docs have /about for Site Homepage and googledocs.com for the webapp
2. Dropbox has dropbox.com for homepage, /home for webapp, paper.dropbox.com for Dropbox Paper
3. Asana has asana.com as homepage and app.asana.com for webapp

---

**Current Working Solution:**

Designed all these sections in single Angular 4 Application, build app, upload on firebase hosting in firebase project.

**Concern with current solution:**

1. I have no idea how these do that in background.
2. With Current Solution:
   2.1 app will keep growing and Firebase Database will be a mess. 
   2.2 Size of app will be bigger and dependency tree will be bigger.

Q : Are above concerns justified ?

---

**This is what I intend to do:**

1. I want to separate Site, App and Blog into their own projects.
2. In future, I want to separate /projects and /tasks in my Webapp into two different apps.

**And this is where I am unable to decide.**

**Concerns:**

Separate root folders (after separating ) will have separate build files (dist folder), I can only upload one set of dist folder to firebase hosting.

Q: Can I achieve what I mentioned above within firebase or do I need any server-side code or firebase functions.

So, the question boils down to Hosting Multiple Angular 4 apps on a single firebase project + hosting + domain

---

**Solution in my mind:**

1. create multiple firebase projects (already looks like a bad approach, but hey)  and in custom domain give www.mysite.com/blog as the domain
2. Or, custom domain can be app.mysite.com and blog.mysite.com
3. With domain provider, use redirect like /about to page made with vanilla html , css and host on say godaddy, heroku.
4. Use redirect for /blog to wordpress site.

I am ready for any solution. But more importantly I want a mental model to approach this.